# control characters check taking too long to load

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to search for special characters in a string.

If the **special character** exists in the string then the code would return a false to the adjacent cell.

```
Dim arr(5)

arr(1) = "19"
arr(2) = "26"
arr(3) = "29"
arr(4) = "32"
arr(5) = "50"

'control characters check
For n = 1 To 5
    For x = 1 To 41
        If InStr(1, Range("b" & arr(n)), Chr(x)) = 0 Then
            For y = 123 To 255
                If InStr(Range("b" & arr(n)).Value, Chr(y)) > 0 Then
                    Range("e" & arr(n)).Value = "FALSE"
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Range("e" & arr(n)).Value = "TRUE"
                End If
            Next y
        Else
            Range("e" & arr(n)).Value = "FALSE"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
Next n
```

My problem is, just looping a few times took quite a long time, is there a faster way to loop through all the data saving more time?

An example of the string data in the cell is : `TY56D-CAT131BP342AC46-eL-W-00`

Comment: have you set calculation to manual?

Comment: can you provide an example string?

Comment: TY56D-CAT131BP342AC46-eL-W-00 << this this is the kind of string @UGP

Comment: @Nathan_Sav what do you mean by manual?

Comment: Have you considered using `Regex`?

Comment: you read too many cells, and you read the same cell multiple times wich is useless. Reverse the loops, (x first, n in second), read the cell and put it in a string variable, then loop on n. Also i would recommend using VBA array. All this together wouldn't take more than 0.5 seconds, my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim arr(5) As String
Dim iLen As Integer, strV As String
Dim Found As Boolean: Found = False
Dim Test As Variant

arr(1) = "19"
arr(2) = "26"
arr(3) = "29"
arr(4) = "32"
arr(5) = "50"

For x = 1 To 5
    iLen = Len(Range("B" & arr(x)).Value)
    strV = Range("B" & arr(x)).Value
    For i = 1 To iLen
        Select Case Asc(Mid$(strV, i, 1))
        Case 1 To 41, 123 To 255
            Found = True
            Exit For
        End Select
    Next i
    If Found = False Then
       Range("E" & arr(x)).Value = "TRUE"
    Else
        Found = False
        Range("E" & arr(x)).Value = "FALSE"
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Calculation time is nearly instant. What differs to your method is, that i go through every characters and then check if its allowed or not. In this case the `Select Case` can do this much quicker than a for loop for every unallowed char.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're being slowed down a lot by referring to

```
Range("b" & arr(n)).Value
```

potentially up to 120+ times in the loop (which is itself nested in other loops)

What should immediately improve the speed of your macro is to transfer the Range value to a variable before this loop, for example:

```
dim search_string as string
search_string = Range("b" & arr(n)).Value

For y = 123 To 255
     If InStr(search_string, Chr(y)) > 0 Then
     Range("e" & arr(n)).Value = "FALSE"
```

You'd also save a bit of time converting your whole search range to an array and working on that, but that would take more work, whereas this is a quick change you can make which should drastically improve performance

Comment: Typo in your answer - should be `If InStr(search_string, Chr(y)) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CheckCharacters()
    Dim cl(5) As Integer, n As Integer

    cls = Array(19, 26, 29, 32, 50)

    For n = 0 To 4
        If IsValidString(Range("B" & cls(n))) Then
            Range("B" & cls(n)).Offset(0, 3) = "TRUE"
        Else
            Range("B" & cls(n)).Offset(0, 3) = "FALSE"
        End if
    Next n
End Sub

Function IsValidString(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegEx As Object

    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    objRegEx.Pattern = "^[\x2a-\x7a]+"
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True

    IsValidString = objRegEx.test(str)
End Function
```

The important bit is:

```
"^[\x2a-\x7a]+"
```

This is a `Regex` that is only TRUE if the string only contains characters between ASCII values 42 and 122 (which is what you want).